# Getting shiro session from atmosphereresource

Tags: java, session, shiro, atmosphere

I am using the below code to get the session from an atmosphereresource:

```
 WebEnvironment env = WebUtils.getRequiredWebEnvironment(r.getAtmosphereConfig().getServletContext());

Session session = new WebSubject.Builder(env.getSecurityManager(), r.getRequest(), r.getResponse()).buildWebSubject().getSession();
```

I have also tried getting the session from session id in the following way:

```
WebEnvironment env = WebUtils.getRequiredWebEnvironment(r.getAtmosphereConfig().getServletContext());
Session s = new Subject.Builder(env.getSecurityManager()).sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject().getSession();
```

However, it returns a session with null principals for a authenticated user with a valid session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you wrote is exactly what `ShiroInterceptor` does. If you do not specify a session manager in your `.INI` file, it will use `ServletContainerSessionManager`.
From the documentation of `ServletContainerSessionManager`:

> Despite its name, this implementation does not itself manage Sessions
>   since the Servlet container provides the actual management support.
>   This class mainly exists to 'impersonate' a regular Shiro
>   SessionManager so it can be pluggable into a normal Shiro
>   configuration in a pure web application.

However changing the session manager to some other implementation like  `DefaultWebSessionManager` will fix the problem and you will be able to get the current Subject and session.